# PHP urlencode by RFC 2396

Tags: php, urlencode, rfc2396

Is there some way in php to encode the url, but according to [RFC 2396](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt).

[rawurlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) is by RFC 3986

[urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) - RFC 1738 ? (its not RFC 2396 anyway)

I also checked [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php), but its 4th param can be only `PHP_QUERY_RFC1738` or `PHP_QUERY_RFC3986`.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to use RFC2396? It was obsoleted by RFC3986 over a decade ago!

Comment: @Quentin, I am aware of that, but I should submit RFC2396 encoded url to 3rd party, which I have no control over: with other 2 encodings it does not work. So, I am not really using it, just need to have the final encoding with that standard. thanks

Comment: What sequence of characters do you need to send which encodes differently between 2396 and 3986?

Comment: @Quentin, not really sure, because its like this - I am getting some response, then based on that response should create that encoded url. One example of right encoded chars is this: colon ":" and dash "-" are not encoded, slash "/" encoded. thanks